# Display multiple images from database using PDO mysql

Tags: php

The situation: I could show only one image at a time.

Problem: Show images from the database into a web page.

Comment: Thank you for your promptness in response, I was arranging the formatting of the question when I saw the issues, and I thank you. Now I feel a Suggested.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario Thank you, but maybe you did not understand my question, most likely because of my English.

Comment: @user2231935 Álvaro's question is reasonable. You have one request, which returns one image. A typical approach is to have multiple requests, one for each image. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to get: View multiple image in a sub-page using GET request, everything works for a single image, but need to view a group in the secondary page can have different:
    echo "<img src='image.php?id_inter=".$id_inter."' />";
But the code does not provide me with more than one image. Thanks to you too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the ID selected, but it should be that way:

```
while($row = $statement->fetch()) { ?>
<img src="image.php?id_inter=<?= $row['id']; ?>" />
...
<?php } ...
```

if you use the ID from the GET method as seems to be stated in
     ( try { $requestedID = (int)$_GET['id_inter']; })

then simply

```
..."id_inter=<?= $reuqestedID; ?>"
```

Comment: I repeat that code for a single image is fine, but do not know how to set up a foreach or while loop to make an array. By entering the ID number in the place indicated above I can see one of the photos. Thanks again for any help

Comment: Well, let's go back to the logic of the code. You have selected cols -> imgMime, imgSize, imgData ... WHERE column ID is $id_inter. This $id_inter is filled from the user via GET METHOD. So you expect only one ID given by the user, which will output only one row, so only one result will be given. this ID is not an array, the result is not an array.

Comment: is not the case, the id is not unique, there is a group picture with this in_inter. Sorry for not making it clear before. ;-)

Comment: you need unique index for this: `<img src="image.php?param=value" />` I think it could be imgMime? How do you access a single image? Your while loop iterates through the columns, which should be different if ID = 3 returns 10 results for example. You will have 10 different imgMimes and imgData's I guess. You can use them inside the loop

Comment: Volevo Scrivere id_inter sopra.

Comment: but it's equal to all the results, even you recieve 3 `<img>` tags they will have 10 equivalent images, because their SRC will be the one and the same

Comment: In fact, some images are jpeg or png , then mime varies, imgData are called by this id_inter, then on another page I get the request through and I can see the image, but all that I see is that they need to id_inter. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

New answer since it's not well formated as comment

SELECT imgMime, imgSize, imgData FROM TableName WHERE id_inter = 3;

//if that returns 2 results:

```
id_inter    |   imgMime     |   imgSize     |   imgData     |

3           |   jpeg        |   100kb       |   data1       |
3           |   png         |   300kb       |   data2       |
```

then

```
while($row = $statement->fetch()) { ?>
<img src="image.php?data=<?= $row['imgData']; ?>"><br />
<?php } ?>
```

should output:

```
<img src="image.php?data=data1"><br />
<img src="image.php?data=data2"><br />
```

if you use id_inter, you will output

```
<img src="image.php?id=3"><br />
<img src="image.php?id=3"><br />
```

Give us an example with HTML, how it should work with i.e. 3 results?

Comment: Looking at the code in the original question, we see that the header ('Content-type:'. $ ImgMime) appears in the call to the image, I have to stick to what approach.  (my ignorance is still embarrassing, but I'm trying.)

Comment: we're almost there, now I've tried it and I see two small "icons" image not loaded, I see how I do with imgMime, and I think it will be fine.

Comment: how a single image is called. $imgData.$imgMime ? Give us an URL of a single image, when you call it staticly

Comment: the images are jpeg and / or png so you have to call $ imgMime this means that the header of course had to come before the echo of the image, just like the code in question. I hope to be able to explain.

Comment: The code above is in image.php page that is called via the GET method from another page with its tag " <img src = ... " my problem is on the page in which the image.php code returns only one image of the column id_inter not unique, I would like to see the image of the group id_inter.
My question concerns the $imgMime and the while loop.
Should I set a foreach? If so, how should I proceed? Thanks for any help.*

Comment: What does your DB output, when you make a SELECT with an existent inter_id. Give us an example from your DB result. And give us an example how your image.php opens an image

Comment: the image.php is exactly the code above, you see the "echo $ imgData;" at the end of the code. If I enter in the browser http://localhost/image.php?id_inter=3 Viewing a single picture of the 3 possible with the same id_inter. Instead, the call is inserted GET to another page with the appropriate tag <img src='image.php?id_inter=3 />. Perhaps it is in the latter that I do a foreach, but at this point grope in the dark. We take as a reference always the code above, we can see that the Mime is called in the header ('Content-type:'. $ ImgMime); ...

Comment: Even if you make your image.php to show 3 images, you cannot call all of them by `<img>`. Strict to one file one image. I will leave the discussion here, because I'm no longer able to help. If someone else got a solution, will be glad to read it. :) Wish you good luck :)